# AWS instance not showing the correct free space

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, du, linux-disk-free

I use AWS and I got an EC2 instance.
When I run the command
`du -h --max-depth=1`

I get:

[image]

and When I run the command 
`df -h`

I get:

[image]

It look I use only 1GB but it show that I am using 7.1GB. 
So I run the command lsof +L1 to locate some deleted file that process are still using and I found 2 of them:

[image]

Then I try to kill those processes,also try to use /proc/PID/fd (> FD) and I try to restart my EC2 instance but none of those thing help me to free the space.
The process are always return and I can't figure up why.

Comment: possible dup of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41863/how-to-remember-the-difference-between-du-and-df

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`du` begins in the current directory. Change the directory:

```
cd /
```

Then try your `du` command again.

Alternatively, tell `du` to start with the root directory:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 /
```

Reference and further reading: http://www.linfo.org/du.html